# why same code in the different set synthesize method works different?

Tags: ios, objective-c, synthesize

In the `setProgram` and `setGraphic` methods we have the same code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.display);
```

But the output shows that self.display is **null** in `setProgram`, but is a **UILable object** in `setGraphic`.

What causes the different result?`display` is IBOutlet and `program` is NSArray object. While `program` is the model of the SOGraphicViewController, I will pass the value of program from another controller by `[segue.destinationViewController setProgram: self.brain.program]`.

```
@interface SOGraphicViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet graphicView *graphic;
@end

@implementation SOGraphicViewController

@synthesize program = _program;
@synthesize graphic = _graphic;
@synthesize display = _display;

- (void)setProgram:(id)program {
    _program = program;
    [self.graphic setNeedsDisplay];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.display);
}

- (void)setGraphic:(graphicView *)graphic {
    _graphic = graphic;
    self.graphic.dataSource = self;
    NSLog(@"%@", self.display);
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling this methods, in order to see the NSLog?

Comment: When in the process (compared to where setPRogram and setGraphic are) do you create self.display? Is it created in code, or is it an IBOutlet?

Comment: Note: `@synthesize` is not needed, they will be automatically generated with the ivars prefixed with an underscore. Nor do the ivars need to be explicitly declared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that your properties are all `IBOutlets`, then the best guess is that the setters are being called during XIB loading and `display` is set in between `program` and `graphic` being set.

That is, as the XIB is unarchived, the setters are being called as the objects are reconstituted.  The order is undefined.

(This amused me; I ran into the same confusion when I was first learning about NIB loading ~23 years ago.  BTW: Ya'll can get off my lawn.)

Given that those are outlets, there is no need to call `setNeedsDisplay`.  In fact, you shouldn't override the setters at all.

Also, class names always start with a capital letter.

Comment: And nowadays class names should have prefixes, like ICEGraphicViewController.

Comment: @bbum Why you youngster, I've been coding 39+ years (and computers are my 3rd profession). Oh, feel free to use my lawn. :-)